# Changing Perspective of vector (considering the cv::warpPerspective )

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

say I have a source image than I transform to a dst image using getPerspectiveTransform and cv::warpPerspective. after that I have special vector of points  in my source image, and I want to get or rather draw them in my  dst image , I thought  it'll obvious, but I don't this done , to better explain the problem I have a sample with a chessboard:

```
.................................
transformationMatrix= cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src_Point, quad_pts);
            cv::warpPerspective(src, dst, transformationMatrix, dst.size()/,CV_INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_ISOLATED);
```

this work fine so Now I've changed the perspective of my src frame.  to transform my Points and theen put them in the dst I wrote this small function

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> warpStuff(std::vector<cv::Point2f> inputVector , cv::Mat transformationMatrix){
    cv::Matx33f warp = transformationMatrix;
    cv::Point3f homogenous;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> result;

    for (int k  =0;  k < inputVector.size()-1; k++ ){
        homogenous = warp* inputVector[k];
        result.push_back(cv::Point2f(homogenous.x,homogenous.y));
    }

    return result;
}
```

when try to draw the result vector in dst I don't get the points in their position ?

here's my source image
[image: the source]

and after the transformation, when draw result here' a what I get :

[image: the dst image]

I think the problem is that cv::warpPerspective is using in addition to the transformation matrix the size of the dst image, I tried to debugg the stuff but I really didn't understand what does it do with this size so I can  add this to my function !

any suggestion ?

Comment: Just a quick note: input vector has 2D points, you are using 3D rotation matrix and 3D point to do transform. Mathematically, at least, it does not seem right.

Comment: well actually, it's right because I don't care about Z value

Comment: Second parameter to the function, `cv::Mat transformationMatrix` - is it actually 2x2 matrix when you pass it to the function?

Comment: it's a 3x3 Matrix I calculated befor, it's the result of cv::getPectiveTransform() and use  it in warpPerspective as well

Comment: In mathematics, you cannot multiply 3x3 matrix by 2x1 matrix (2D vector). Maybe, OpenCV handles it somehow, but it has no mathematical sense... On a side note, shouldn't it be `k < inputVector.size();`?

Comment: 1. opencv hasn't a problem with this multiplication and I using inputVector[k] so I have to go tell size-1 ! the syntax is correct U only have to consider the  the size of my dst frame and I don't know how to do it

Comment: @PetrBudnik   I think that OpenCV put put z=1